# Association between two polymorphic models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, polymorphic-associations, belongs-to

I have `Vote` and `Voting` models.

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
end

class Voting < ActiveRecord::Base
  #this model keeps track of positive and negative votes

  belongs_to :votingable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Both of them share the same owner for example `Post` so compared `voteable_id`, `votingable_id` and `voteable_type`, `votingable_type` are same for both potential objects.

How do I implement an association where `Vote` `belongs_to :voting` and `Voting` 
`has_many :votes` ?

For now I just delegate `voting` to `voteable` and vice versa which is not a satisfying solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being slow here, but what is the purpose of the Voting model, over and above Vote?

Comment: `Vote(id: integer, voteable_type: string, voteable_id: integer, voter_id: integer, value: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)` and `Voting(id: integer, votingable_type: string, votingable_id: integer, positive: integer, negative: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)`
When a Vote is saved before_filter updates its Voting depending on value(positive or negative)
So when I would like to get positive votes of an object I just do `post.voting.positive` instead of `post.votes.where(value: 1).count`